# Quick way to create a Master Detail Database viewer

Tags: .net, data-visualization, master-detail

I have a customer that wants to see some data.  I can just sent it to him in an excel file, but the data is master/detail data and it would be nice to send it to him in a tree like form.

Is there an really easy way to put data into some sort of free master detail viewer like that?

Or to code one one **Quick** in C# and visual studio 2008 or 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Or use MS Access.  Two tables and some queries.